# Load data from JSON in picker view

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uipickerview

I get data from a server and I have the following JSON:

```
(
    {
        id = 1;
        status = 1;
        title = "jimmy";
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        status = 1;
        title = "arnold";
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        status = 1;
        title = "mike";
    }
)
```

I want to load the title of this JSON in a picker view and when I select one of them, the id of the selected row is set in the myID variable.
I wrote the below code but the picker view doesn't show anything:

```
var dictionary = [[String : AnyObject]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerDep.delegate = self
    pickerDep.dataSource = self

    var Token=FuncClass.ReadData(_file: "fileToken.txt")
    let url=Property._URL+"getTicketDepartment"
    let parameters = [
        "token": Token
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in
        if let data = response.data {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)

            let result=response.result
            self.dictionary = (result.value as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>])!
        }
    }
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dictionary.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return dictionary[row]["title"] as! String
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the picker view after the data is loaded from Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in
    if let data = response.data {
        let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)

        let result=response.result
        if let array = result.value as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {
            self.dictionary = array
            pickerDep.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
}
```

BTW - why is your property named `dictionary` when it contains an array of data?

Comment: thank you,it work.   yes, that name is my mistake. so, now how can i get id of selected row?

Comment: That's a separate question. This one is about getting the picker view loaded. But as a hint, implement the `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` method.

Comment: i write this code for get id: func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       
        var dict = self.dictionary[row]
        selectedDepID = String(describing: dict["id"])
    }            this is true but first, it not return first row. but if i change picker value and again return first row, it i ok.   why?????

Comment: Never use `String(describing:)` to show a value to a user or to convert a value to a String. It's only for debugging.

Comment: so what should i use instead of describing?

Comment: If the id is a `Int` then `selectedDepID` should be an `Int`. But if you really need to convert the id to a String then use `selectedDepID = "\(dict["id"]!)"`. But this assumes `dict` is guaranteed to have a value for the `"id"` key.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but i also faced up this problem. When i use reloadAllComponents() in override func viewDidLoad() in my app, my app hangs up for 4-5 sec. then refresh pickerView or crash. I solved this problem adding DispatchQueue feature. My solution to this post is,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    pickerDep.reloadAllComponents()
}
```